# Can I make this "stopwatch" any simpler?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a stopwatch timer in JS that only activates once and keeps going forever. I wonder if any of you have an idea on how to make it more simple since i'm new to JS and this was the only thing I could come up with that work as i want.

This is the timer:

```
let time = 0
let activated = 0

function changePic() {

    if(activated == 0) {
        interval()
        activated++
    }
}

function interval() {
    setInterval(timer, 1000)
}

function timer() {
    time++
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = time + " seconds"

}
```

*I cut some of the unneccesary code out*

Now I just wonder if:

1. I can make it simpler
2. How do I make a button to stop the "stopwatch timer"

Important to know is it's only supposed to be activated once until you stop it then it should count from 0 when you activate it again.

Comment: Are you sure you want it simpler? [JavaScript counters the hard way - HTTP 203](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCi6AZMkxcU).

Comment: Note that the interval isn't perfect, so you are counting firings and not '1000 ms' intervals exactly.  It could be 900 or 1100 ms, or even 2000+ ms if the browser is busy, but that would be rare for a simple app.  And if you stop and restart the interval you will lose partial seconds when stopping.  But since you are asking for simplicity instead of accuracy I will assume that doesn't matter for this.

Comment: For what i'm making that kind of accuracy is not really needed but thank's for pointing it out for me @JasonGoemaat :)

Comment: Couple things to consider: 1. functions triggered via `setInterval` or `setTimeout` run after _at least_ `delay` has elapsed and the call stack is empty. It may be longer than your specified delay. This could cause your `time++` to drift a bit. If you want it to be precise you should capture the start time and subtract it from the current time on each tick instead. 2. You're starting _another_ interval timer each time you invoke `changePic`, which is going to cause your display to update multiple times. You can use `clearInterval` to stop the previous one.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This forum is for help with code that isn't working. For advice on how to improve working code, check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not a simplification, but ways to make it clearer — Activated seems to be a boolean, so make it a boolean. Improve names: Use nouns (for values), verbs (for procedures that do something) and adjectives (for booleans). e.g. changePic →initialise, timer → do_tick, interval →initialise (combine with the other initialise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setinterval return timerId. use timerid to close timer.

```js
let time = 0;
let intervalId;

function toggleTimer() {
    if (intervalId) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        intervalId = null;
        time = 0;
    } else {
        intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            time++;
            document.getElementById("timer").textContent = time + " seconds";
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

```html
 <button onclick="toggleTimer()">start Timer</button>
<div id="timer"></div>
```